# How can I extract a 6 digit number from the text in excel? Examples shown below

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I want to extract a pincode from the address. For example, I want to extract 751003 from below address:

Siksha O Annushandhan University, Extension of Sum Hospital,Khandagiri,K-8,Bhubaneswar-751003,Odisha

and another example, I want to extract 799001 from below address:
Saha Drug Distributors; Santipara,Maszid Road,Agartala-799 001,Tripura

Comment: Your second example actually appears to want to match _two_ numbers, separated by whitespace, and then return just a single number, with no whitespace.  Can you explain this more?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are correct. They are Postal Pin Codes used in India. They are 6 digit always. Sometimes, people may use a single space notation after 3rd digit like OP's second example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your data starts in cell A2, try below formula.

```
=LOOKUP(1,1/MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""),ROW($A$1:$A$199),6),MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""),ROW($A$1:$A$199),6))
```

Note for OP: SO Expects user to attempt a solution and include description of attempt and difficulty faced.

**Edit**: See below edit.

```
=LOOKUP(1,1/MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")&"a",ROW($A$1:$A$199),6),MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""),ROW($A$1:$A$199),6))
```

Comment: Perfect...Thank you...this works for the  examples given....however, this doesnt work for  address like "Gala No 3, Sr No 234-235, Tal Mulshi, Hinjewadi, Pune - 411057"....I can use a simple Right formula, however, it will be great, If i have one single formula to take care of all 3 examples shared so far....Thank you again

Comment: And one more varient please ""Gala No 3, Sr No 234-235, Tal Mulshi, Hinjewadi, Pune - 411 057"" (Space in pincode)..Thank you

Comment: +1 Good job, the OP @sagardbhangale should provide sufficient sample data including all possible variations before asking for help, especially in this type of question.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij outstanding...Thank you..this works perfectly...

Answer (score 2):

Try using regular expressions:

```
Sub ExtractCode()
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    ' pattern explanation: \d{6} - match 6 digits
    regex.Pattern = "\d{6}"
    ' Get address from cell A1 and remove all spaces
    testString = Replace(Cells(1, 1), " ", "")
    MsgBox regex.Execute(testString)(0).Value
    ' Get address from cell A2 and remove all spaces
    testString = Replace(Cells(2, 1), " ", "")
    MsgBox regex.Execute(testString)(0).Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Example I used

```
Saha Drug Distributors; Santipara,Maszid Road,Agartala-799 001,Tripura
```

U can use the following formulas to extract Pin Code:

```
=MID(TRIM(A1),FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",CHAR(1),LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",""))))-3,7)
```

**Or**

```
=MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+1,7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather easy approach considering the following data:

[image]

```
Sub GetVals()

Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
Dim lr As Long

With Sheet1 'Change accordingly
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lr)
    For Each cl In rng
        cl.Offset(0, 1) = Val(Mid(cl, InStrRev(cl, "-") + 1, Len(cl)))
    Next cl
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

`Val` will get the numberic values from the position of the last "-" (found through `InstrRev` without the space (as your wanted result in the question shows).